# Django get_or_create returns False

Tags: python, mysql, django, populate

I'm creating a population script, from an MysqlDatabase to Django Models.
Im looping through my receiving data from the Mysql and thats going good.

Now I have to write it to the Django Database...

```
mdl, succeeded = models.User.objects.get_or_create(
    name=name,
    password=password,
    email=email
)
```

I'm printing `succeeded` so I can see what the feedback is, but all it gives me is `False`

My Django Model `User` is edited so all fields can be `blank` and allows `NULL` or have a default

My Model `User`:

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
name = models.CharField("First and last name", max_length=100)
uses_metric = models.BooleanField(default=True)
position = models.CharField("Position", max_length=70, blank=True, null=True,)
utility = models.ForeignKey(Utility, default=1, blank=True, null=True)
supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, default=1, blank=True, null=True)
currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, default=1)
phone = models.CharField("Direct phone number", max_length=40, blank=True,  default='+')
gets_notifications_on_reply = models.BooleanField("Receive notifications", default=False)
memberlist = models.BooleanField("Show member in memberslist", default=True)
registration_date = models.IntegerField(default=floor(time.time()), blank=True, null=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(
    _('staff status'),
    default=False,
    help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this site.'),
)
is_active = models.BooleanField(
    _('active'),
    default=True,
    help_text=_(
        'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
        'Deselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
    ),
)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check your database. This means that the User objects you are querying from there already exists. This might be due to the object already existing or alternatively your code not using the correct database. Since migrations, often use multiple databases this might be a problem as well.

[According to the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), `get_or_create()` does not return an object and a status `succeeded` but instead a flag `created`, which indicates if this object has been newly created or already existed in the database. If it already existed, the `created` flag (`succeeded` in your code) is `False`.

If you want to make sure that the error is not due to objects already existing, take one data pair for which `created` is false and try to retrieve it using the model's `get()` method. If this throws a `DoesNotExist` error then something else is the problem. If it returns an object then that object already existed.

Comment: + I've tried created as well, did exactly the same. :(

Comment: Renaming the flag will not change that it has the same information. Please check again that you really removed all new data or try with different values.
Is it always returning `False` or just on some requests? It might also be that you are trying to import the same data twice. You could also check that by using the same data to just `get()` a user. If this succeeds in returning you a user, then it existed before.

Comment: @ChickenWing1996, I quickly also added the hint about `get()` into my answer to collect all relevant information up there as well. Feel free to ask further questions, if my answer does not solve your problem yet.

Comment: I've found the problem, it has to do with that I didn't select the right database. So stupid, Thanks for your time

Comment: Of course, if you select the wrong database then the data may already exist. You are welcome. I will update my answer to also contain that hint. Could you then please mark it as the correct answer so that future users with the same problem directly know where to look?